# Converting function to use iteration

Tags: c, for-loop, recursion, iteration

I have written a recursive function to access array elements. Every 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and so on to 150. I want to do the same thing but with iteration. I have coded something below, the first example it runs but i'm not sure its correct and works the same as the first function. I know i'm using two for loops to do this i may have placed the index var in wrong spot.

```
void openarray(skip)
{
    int i;
    for(i = skip; i < 150; i+=skip + 1) 
    {
        if(arrayB[i] == open)
        {
            arrayB[i] = close;
        }
        else
        {
            arrayB[i] = open;
        }
    }
    if(skip < 150)
    {
        openarray(skip + 1);
    }
}
```

my code to turn into iteration i think i may have confused the index for step or vice versa.

```
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < 150; i++) 
{
    for (j = 0; j < 150; j+=i + 1)
    if(arrayB[i] == open)
    {
        arrayB[i] = close;
    }
    else
    {
        arrayB[i] = open;
    }
}
```

Comment: "i'm not sure its correct and works the same as the first function". That's what testing is for. Design your tests and run them. If the results are wrong then you know the code is not correct. From there you would then start debugging. Posting on Stackoverflow is not the first step of testing or debugging.

Comment: @kaylum ive tried ALL DAY ive been printing out all the index and skip i cant figure it out you dont think ive been testing and trying things that a rude assumption...

Comment: Then why don't you say that? Share your testing result - input, expected output, actual output. That and a [mcve] are what all SO questions should have to help the reader know what your specific issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Let's put the recursive call at the very end.

```
void openarray(skip)
{
    int i;
    for(i = skip; i < 150; i+=skip + 1) 
    {
        if(arrayB[i] == open)
        {
            arrayB[i] = close;
        }
        else
        {
            arrayB[i] = open;
        }
    }

    if(skip >= 150)
        return;

    openarray(skip + 1);
}
```

Step 2: Add the loop.

```
void openarray(skip)
{
    while (1) {
        int i;
        for(i = skip; i < 150; i+=skip + 1) 
        {
            if(arrayB[i] == open)
            {
                arrayB[i] = close;
            }
            else
            {
                arrayB[i] = open;
            }
        }

        if(skip >= 150)
            return;

        skip = skip + 1;
    } 
}
```

Step 3: Clean up

```
void openarray(skip)
{
    for (; skip < 150; ++skip)
    {
        int i;
        for(i = skip; i < 150; i+=skip + 1) 
        {
            if(arrayB[i] == open)
            {
                arrayB[i] = close;
            }
            else
            {
                arrayB[i] = open;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

We can compare this against your code to see what errors you made:

- You initialized the outer loop counter to zero.
- You used the outer loop counter as the array index instead of the inner loop counter.

Comment: You are making an answer based on **unclear and uncomplete question**. What is the range of `skip` variable ? Try with `openarray(-1)` and see.

Comment: @Meninx - メネンックス, I don't see the issue. Both the reference recursive implementation and the provided iterative implementation work the same for `openarray(-1)` (even though it's obviously not a valid input).

Comment: @ikegami thank you i think this works! testing now seems to have same output as recursive approach